# Название файлов темы

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть код .php, в котором находится код шаблона (шаблон я скачал с официального сайта WordPress), у меня такой вопрос, вот я открыл файл header.php, и в нем я нашел такой путь к файлу .php , то есть, я сразу понял, что это путь к определенному файлу .php , но я перешел по этой ссылке непосредственно в папку с этими файлами, но файл с именем header я не нашел там, но там был другой файл с именем header-image.php . 
Почему так файлы прописаны? Может файлы так прописываются в .php в CMS WordPress ?

Comment: 1. https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F 2. https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2

Answer (score 0):

Это смысловое название. Видимо, заголовок сайта будет в виде картинки, которая погрузиться из папки images.

Comment: Но почему код был следующим: <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/header/header', 'image' ); ?> то есть, в этой папке были только .php файлы и все, а вот изображения там не было

Comment: в какой папке? изображения всегда находятся в другой папке и это разумно.

Comment: Это да! Но изображение хранятся у меня в папке images, внутри папки assets ...